# Significato di "colpo d'occhio" in questo brano

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *Ferito a morte*, di Raffaele La Capria, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Devi vedere anche la Mostra d’Oltremare con le fontane luminose, sfumature bellissime, *mauve*, *fraise*, *beige*, ti dico un **colpo d’occhio**!... Un’altra idea di Lauro.

La mia domanda è sul significato di "colpo d'occhio" in questo passaggio.

Sul [vocabolario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/colpo) ho trovato:

> *C. d’occhio*, vista, veduta, spec. panoramica, dall’alto; o anche, occhiata, il vedere (e il saper vedere) a un tratto: *si distingue a c. d’occhio*, subito, alla prima; *è un uomo che ha un c. d’occhio sicuro*.

E anche sul [De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/colpo-docchio) si legge:

> **colpo d’occhio** 
> loc.s.m.   
> CO 
> veduta d’insieme, panoramica: dalla terrazza c’è un bel colpo d’occhio | occhiata veloce, sguardo rapido: il colpo d’occhio dell’artista; a colpo d’occhio, a prima vista, subito: riconoscere qcn. a colpo d’occhio

Tuttavia, non mi sembra che queste accezioni, espresse esattamente in questo modo, siano adatte al contesto del testo. Ho la sensazione che si usi "colpo d'occhio" per descrivere qualcosa (quelle fontane con tutti quei colori) che produce una certa impressione alla vista. È così? Cosa significa "colpo d'occhio" in questo contesto?

**Aggiornamento:**

Sul libro [*Breve descrizione della città di Napoli e del suo contorno*](https://books.google.es/books?id=KWc5AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA2&dq=%22Questa+capitale+col+suo+cratere,+colle+sue+isole+e+montagne+forma+un+colpo+d%27occhio+ed+una+bellezza+di+situazione+la+pi%C3%B9+singolare%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjN2cG1sIv2AhWLyIUKHcYCAEoQ6AF6BAgEEAE#v=onepage&q=%22Questa%20capitale%20col%20suo%20cratere%2C%20colle%20sue%20isole%20e%20montagne%20forma%20un%20colpo%20d%27occhio%20ed%20una%20bellezza%20di%20situazione%20la%20pi%C3%B9%20singolare%22&f=false)
di Giuseppe Maria Galanti ho trovato un brano in cui credo (potrei però sbagliarmi) si faccia un uso simile di questa locuzione (il grassetto è sempre mio):

> Questa capitale col suo cratere, colle sue isole e montagne forma un **colpo d'occhio** ed una bellezza di situazione la più singolare.

Comment: La tua interpretazione è secondo me corretta; il significato della frase è quello che hai trovato, ma in questo caso il significato è quello che hai detto tu.... potremmo anche dire che c'è un'aggettivo sottointeso, tipo "che (bel) colpo d'occhio" o "che (magnifico) colpo d'occhio".